# Access parent li within nested child in an unorderlist

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have following structure with nested unordered list. I currently got handle of child selector. From the child selector I want to change the class name of top parent li from static collapsed to static expanded. Below is sample and I can have any number of nested children.

```html
<ul>
<li class="static collapsed">
 <ul class = "static">
  <li class ="static"></li> // I am looking to access the parent li from here
 </ul>
<li class="static collapsed"></li>
<li class="static collapsed"></li>
</ul>
```

I tried below options but that could only change the class for the inner(child) li and ul but cant access the parent li.

$(this).addClass('Vanilla');
$(this).parents("ul:first").addClass('Choclate');

Any ideas on how can I change the top li's class name using child selector. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to access the first matched parent

```
$(this).closest('li')
```

Comment: When I try these... alert($(this).closest('li').attr('class')); it gives me static. It doesn't give me static collapsed. I want to access top most li.

Comment: @PradeepReddy, how do you use this code? please put your complete code here.

Answer (score 0):

This would do that.  Keep in mind your post misspells 'Choclate', but am assuming that was intentional.

`$(this).parents('.static').eq(0).addClass('choclate');`

Adjust eq for how many levels up you need to go.  In this case, one level up should do it.  To go up one level, leave it at zero.  For two, put it at 1, and so on.

Another option would be to add a class unique to the parent li's, so it can simply reach for those via something like  `.parents('.parentli')`.

Comment: All of the my top li have unique class 'static collapsed' and I tried your answer  $(this).parents('.static collapsed').addClass('static expanded');
it didn't work. Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me. 
$(this).closest('.collapsed').attr('class','static expanded');